# UHD ( USRP Hardware Driver) missing dll.file

Tags: c++, windows, boost, uhd

I am trying to implement Boost and UHD in a windows VS2015. I installed Boost . I downloaded the binary, installed  it, build builder with bootstrap.bat then build it with

```
bjam --build-dir=build-directory --toolset=msvc14.0  address-model=64 --build-type=complete stage
```

I installed UHD from [Ettus](http://files.ettus.com/binaries/uhd/latest_release/) `uhd_3.10.1.1-release_x64_VS2015.exe`. Then I started my project. I linked all the libraries.

1: VC++ Directories > Executable Directories > ...\UHD\bin ( as an attempt to solve this problem)

2: C/C++ > General> Additional include directories ...\boost_1_63_0; 
 ...\UHD\bin;  ...\UHD\include;

3: Linker > General > Additional Library Directories :
...\UHD\lib; ..\boost_1_63_0\stage\lib; ...\boost_1_63_0;

4: Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > uhd.lib

When I launch my own or example code from [GitHub](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/blob/master/host/examples/rx_samples_to_file.cpp) I get an error saying that the code cant be execute because uhd.dll file is missing. If I put the uhd.dll file in the VS project directory I get access violation: 0xC0....05. Has anyone encountered this issue before ?

Comment: you need to *either* download binary boost or build it from scratch. Doing both is basically a recipe for conflicts, and I'd very much guess that's the reason for your access violation. The fact that uhd.dll needs to be in the PATH or the same directory as the executable is absolutely normal and just how dynamic linking works under windows.

Comment: I downloaded the binary of the builder, at least from what i understand. I linked and added uhd.dll to the folder, and i still cant launch it. Boost was installed correctly it works for purpouses others then UHD.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: @BastianonMassimo unfortunately no, i was told to focus on something else then stopped working there